# Loading Base64 Encoded Image String into JLabel

Tags: java, swing, base64, jlabel

I got the converter working here

```
public class ImageProcessor {
    public static void Base64TImage(String base64) {
        try {            
            byte[] btDataFile = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(base64);
            File of = new File("yourFile.png");
            FileOutputStream osf = new FileOutputStream(of);
            osf.write(btDataFile);
            osf.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ImageProcessor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String base64 = "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";            
        Base64TImage(base64);
    }
}
```

This converter creates a file and puts it in the current working dir. But i dont want to create a file, I want this image to go directly to the JLabel. Is that possible ?

Comment: When i looked at the API the decode() decodes the string into byte array. Can I use byte array in JLabel to display the image ??

Comment: this is where i was looking http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/xml/internal/messaging/saaj/packaging/mime/util/BASE64DecoderStream.html#decode(byte)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an example based on your code:

```
byte[] btDataFile = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(base64);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(btDataFile));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "", "Image", 
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, 
        new ImageIcon(image));
```

I'd recommend you avoid using `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder`, as `sun.* packages are not part of the supported, public interface`, here are the [details](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html). You can easily switch to [Base64](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) from Apache Commons, ie:

```
byte[] btDataFile = Base64.decodeBase64(base64);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(btDataFile));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "", "Image", 
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, 
        new ImageIcon(image));
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. That really helped me.. I will use this in JLabel and see how it goes.. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

example with http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/

```
    JLabel jLabelImagen = new JLabel(); 
    byte[] imageByte = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(base64); 
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);                         
    BufferedImage bufImage = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(bufImage);
    jLabelImagen.setIcon(icon);
```